# How do I create a linq query that returns the distinct 3 letter prefix of words in a list using deferred execution

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of 50+ variable length words. I need to get an IEnumerable list of just the first 3 characters from each word that is at least 3 characters long and return just the distinct ones using deferred execution. How can I do that using linq in c# 6?

Comment: Have *you* attempted anything yet?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please share it with us

Comment: `words.Where(w => w.Length > 2).Select(w => w.Substring(0,3)).Distinct();`

Comment: `List<string> variableLengthValues=new List<string>()``{"Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"};`     
         `var firstthreeDistinctChars= variableLengthValues.Where(x => x.Length > 3).Select(y => y.Substring(0, 3)).Distinct();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var words = new List<string> {...};
var newWords = words.Where(o = o.Length >= 3).Select(o => o.Substring(0, 3)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<string> result = list.Where(x => x.Length >= 3).Select(x => x.Substring(0, 3)).Distinct();
```